# encoding conflict: php output corrupted by html <head> content

Tags: php, mysql, html, encoding

I'm new to PHP, HTML and MySQL, and have encountered the following problem:

I have a PHP document which outputs the results of a MySQL query. Because the MySQL database and thus the output results have some non-standard characters (such as æ or á), my PHP document and the MySQL database/tables are encoded as utf-8.
For instance, here is an example of the a database entry and correct output:
goahteæjgáda

When the PHP document does not have anything in the HTML `<head/>` node (not even comments), then the search is successful and the output is displayed correctly (but then I can't apply my external css or include the shortcut icon, etc.).

However, if there is *anything at all* in the HTML `<head/>` node, such as standard metadata concerning content type, links to css and icon files, keywords, or even just `<!-- comments -->`, then either:

1. the search does not work if the string being searched for contains a non-standard character 
   OR
2. any non-standard characters in the resulting output are displayed as � -- for instance, the example above shows up like this after searching for "goahte": 
   goahte�jg�da

Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link href='style_mavsulasj.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
  <link rel='shortcut icon' href='farben4.gif'/>
  <title>search</title>
</head>
<body>

<div style="width:230px;padding:0px;margin:0px;float:left;">
<table border="0">
<tr><td>Search here:</td><td>
<?php if (strlen($_GET['smj'])==0) echo ""; else echo "current search"; ?>
</td></tr>
<form action="" method="GET">
<tr><td colspan="2">Entry:</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type='text' name='smj' value=''></input></td><td align='center'><?php echo "<span class='searchCrits' > ".$_GET['smj']."</span>"; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="submit query"/></td></tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>

<div style="width:960px;padding:30px;margin-left:210px;">
<?php
if($_GET){
$smj = $_GET['smj'];
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
    if($connect){    
        $toDB = mysql_select_db("bigG_reimport_test",$connect);
        if($toDB){
            $query = "SELECT * FROM reimport_Sheet1 WHERE smj LIKE '" . $smj . "%'";
            $results = mysql_query($query);
            echo "<span class='header4'>results:<br/>";
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
                echo "-> " . $row['smj'] . "<br/>" ;
                }
            echo "</span><br/>";
            } 
        else {die("Failed to connect to database!<br/>" . mysql_error());}}
        else {die("Failed to connect to mysql!<br/>" . mysql_error());}}
?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What content type is your server returning?  Also, you are **wide open** to SQL injection, and you will undoubtedly be hacked within hours of putting such a script out on the web.  Learn to use prepared queries with PDO.

Comment: This is a great article to read through: http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/charsets

Comment: You can detect the encoding of ``$_GET['smj']`` with ``mb_detect_encoding()``, and convert it with ``iconv()``. If the string is ISO-8859-1, you can also use ``utf8_encode()`` instead of iconv().

Comment: Please read [Handling Unicode in a Webapp](http://kunststube.net/frontback/), it should give you the necessary information.

Comment: @Carpet `mb_detect_encoding` is *not* the right way to detect encodings, since by definition it's impossible to reliably detect unknown encodings automatically. **Specify** the expected encoding, period.

Comment: @Jacob: Thanks for the link to the very useful article!

Comment: @deceze: Thanks for the link to the very useful article!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure:

1. Your PHP source file is encoded as UTF-8 (yes, this really matters, sadly)
2. You've set the charset in your MySQL session to UTF-8.  See [mysql_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php)
3. You set the encoding to UTF-8 in your HTTP headers.

Comment: Step two solved my problem!<br/> I thought I had everything set to UTF-8 (including my SQL database and the relevant table), but after adding  mysql_set_charset('utf8',$connect); just before the query step, the results were encoded correctly.

Comment: But I still don't understand why the problem existed to begin with, in other words, why the presence or absence of anything in the HTML-head node affected the encoding of the output.

Comment: It was probably triggering different browser modes in which the content encoding detection heuristic varied.  I'm not surprised that the meta tag would have caused that, but I don't know why just a comment in a head tag would have done it.  It's definitely interesting.